# How to wrap text with a span tag using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm currently using HtmlAgilityPack to strip the content of a div (with contentEditable) from all the unnecessary Tag, so I can only keep the text between `<p></p>` tag. After getting the text I send it to a corrector that give me back the words in error inside this specifique `<p></p>`.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> DicoError = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
int nbError = 0;
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(texteAFormater);

var nodesSpan = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span");
var nodesA = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");

if (nodesSpan != null)
{
    foreach (var node in nodesSpan)
    {
        node.Remove();
    }
}
if (nodesA != null)
{
    foreach (var node in nodesA)
    {
        if (node.Attributes["edth_type"] != null)
        {
             if (string.Equals(node.Attributes["edth_type"].Value, "contenu", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==false)
             {
                   node.Remove();
             }
         }
    }
}
var paragraphe = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("p");
for(int i =0; i< paragraphe.Count; i++){
    string texteToCorrect = paragraphe[i].innerText;
    List<string> errorInsideParagraph = new List<string>();
    errorInsideParagraph = callProlexis(HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(texteToCorrect), nbError, DicoError);
    for(int j=0;j<motEnErreur.Count; j++){
        HtmlNode spanNode = html.CreateElement("span");
        spanNode.Attributes.Add("class", typeError);
        spanNode.Attributes.Add("id", nbError);
        spanNode.Attributes.Add("oncontextmenu","rightClickMustWork(event, this);return false");
    }
}
```

I manage to send the innerText to my corrector, the worry I got is admitting my innerText for this paragraph is :

```
<p>this is some text <em>error</em> how should this work</p>
```

In this one two words are in error : `error` and `should`

how can I add my `spanNode` so it will keep the `<em></em>` around `error`? (I need to keep the actual tag around the word in error if there is one already and just wrap the `spanNode` around it).

So the expected result will be :

```
<p>this is some text <span ...><em>error</em></span> how <span ...>should</span> this work</p>
```

Edit: I was thinking something like finding the word in error inside the innerHtml then get the parent node of this word, if it is `<p>` then there is no tag around him and we can just add the `spanNode` if it is another tag then we need to add the `spanNode`as his parent node such as `spanNode` is the child of `<p>` but the parent of the tag around this word. I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: What if the same work is present several times in the text? I'd let your corrector function tag the words that are bad. Otherwise there's not way for you to know other than with a find/replace action.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540415/surround-existing-node-with-another-node-with-agility-pack). It offers 2 solutions.