# HtmlAgilityPack adding div elements to existing html file

Tags: c#, html, xml

This is my original html:

```
 <tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 40pt;"><font style="background-color: lightgreen" color="black">Tove</font></td>
    <td style="padding-left: 40pt;"><font style="background-color: lightgreen" color="black">To</font></td>
 </tr>
```

And my goal is to have this:

```
<div class="select-me" /> <tr>...<tr/>
```

I am using HtmlAgilityPack and essentially going through each font tag and checking to see if it's style is light-green. But I'm not sure how to jump to back the table row tags and put a div tag around the table row tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Surround existing node with another node with Agility Pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540415/surround-existing-node-with-another-node-with-agility-pack)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to wrap them with div:

```
foreach(var node in selectMe)
    node.ParentNode.OuterHtml = "<div class=\"select-me\">" + node.ParentNode.InnerHtml + "</div>";
```

Also you can select selectMe with this instead of checking one by one:

```
var selectMe = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[contains(@style,'background-color: lightgreen')]");
```

Comment: for this line of code " node.ParentNode.OuterHtml", I'm getting an error "Property or the indexer 'HtmlNode.OuterHtml' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

Comment: @ErvinWu try this: `node.ParentNode.InnerHtml = "<div class=\"select-me\">" + node.ParentNode.OuterHtml + "</div>";`